# Get MAX value based on specific field

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, simple question: I have a table

```
create table people (
  id int auto_increment not null primary key,
  name varchar(32),
  city varchar(32),
  age int
);
```

with the query

```
SELECT city, age
FROM people
WHERE age=(SELECT max(age) from people);
```

I can get the output of the city and age of the oldest person.

```
City        Age
Denver      95
```

How do I get the max age per city, i.e.

```
City        Age
Atlanta     90
Cincinnati  87
Denver      95
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT city, MAX(age)
FROM people
GROUP BY city
```

This is a use of MySQL aggregate functions.  By providing an additional column and specifying it in the GROUP BY, you are telling MySQL to only apply the aggregation function (in our case MAX) within those matching records.

You can read more about aggregates [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Little description can provide you the upvotes from future visitors

Comment: thanks, could I ask could my original query have been simplified or is it correct _as is_?

Comment: I think it's pretty reasonable, provided you have an index on age.  There are certainly other ways to go about it (see Rahul's answer).  Also, you should be aware that your query will possibly return multiple results if there are others who are the same age (in the same city or not).

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be simplified like

```
SELECT city, age
FROM people
order by age desc
limit 1
```

Comment: It is important to note that these aren't functionally equivalent.  Your query would only ever return 1 result.  The original query would return everyone who is at the max age.

Comment: @Rafa, yep that's a good point. I always get confuse with `asc` and `desc`; and yes the query assuming that multiple result with same max age not present.